# Building with Grunt and Requirejs

Tags: requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am creating a grunt task for building a javascript project with requirejs using grunt-contrib-requirejs

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs

Here is the config:

```
requirejs:
      compile:
        options:
          #appDir: './'
          baseUrl: "client"
          mainConfigFile: "client/main.js"
          name: "main"
          out: "build/main.js"
          wrap:
            start: ""
            end: ""
```

The main.js file requires 2 other files inside subdirectories. Althrough this task does not throw errors, the resulting built file does not run the browser. The files seem to be concatenated since the require calls still exist in the built file. I expect the js files called by require to substitute the require calls, and then be optimized. how can I achieve that?

PS: The config above is written in coffeescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your compiled javascript file to not contain and `require()` or `define()` calls you can use the [AMDclean](https://www.npmjs.org/package/amdclean) npm package and simple add this to your options object:

```js
onModuleBundleComplete: function (data) {
  var fs = require('fs'),
    amdclean = require('amdclean'),
    outputFile = data.path;
  fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, amdclean.clean({
    'filePath': outputFile
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the output javascript is still inside safety wrappers, which prevents the visibility of global variables. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: @EternallyCurious set `wrap: false`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But there's another problem I've described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953007/combining-files-using-requirejs-and-grunt